# Equivalent definition of fractional ideal on ring of integers of a number field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I know the following definition on a Dedekind domain:

Let $D$ be a Dedekind domain and $K$ its field of fractions, then we say that $F$ is a fractional ideal of $D$ if it is a $D$-submodule of $K$ and there exists a $c\in D \setminus \{0_D\}$ such that $cF \subset D$

Now, if we have that $K$ is a number field and $R$ is its ring of integers, as $R$ is a Dedekind domain we can define as before the fractional ideal of $R$ but, in the book *Problems in algebraic number theory* by M. Ray Murty and Jody Esmode, the following definition is given:

Given $K$ a fractional ideal and $R$ is its ring of integers, we say that $F$ is a fractional ideal of $R$ if it is a $R$-submodule of $K$ and there exists a $m \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$ such that $mF \subset R$

It is clear that the general definition implies this one as $\mathbb{Z} \subset R$ but, is this definition in fact equivalent to the general one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case where $R$ is the ring of integers (or more general an order) of a number field $K$ they are equivalent. Suppose that $F$ is a fractional ideal of $R$ in the sense that there is some $s\in R\setminus\{0\}$ with $sF\subseteq R$. Then we can take the norm $m:=N_{K/\Bbb Q}(s)\in \Bbb Z\setminus\{0\}$. Since $s\mid m$ in $R$ we still have $mF\subseteq R$.

A counterexample for the general case of arbitrary Dedekind domains $D$:
Take $D=k[x]$ and $F=\frac{1}{x}D$ where $k$ is any field.